# Unable to retrieve records from HSQL, DB creation is working

Tags: spring, junit, hsqldb

I have an app that is working properly without unit tests, but alas it's the right thing to do.

I'm trying to implement a local HSQL DB for tests.  I know the db is created and the script file is run, because I get SQL errors if there is something wrong with either.  When I try to run the tests, I get 0 results where I think I entered records.  Again, this is all tested through a browser so the `Service` code I'll show is working appropriately.  Also, this is probably a bad test but I'm not here for that.

Here's the test:

```
@Autowired
OfficeService officeServiceImpl;

@Test
@Transactional
public void thatRecordIsSaved() {
    List <Office> offices = officeServiceImpl.findAll();
    Office o = offices.get(0);
    o.setOfficeName("Test office");
    officeServiceImpl.save(o);
    List<Office> officesAfter = officeServiceImpl.findAll();
    Office lastLocation = officesAfter.get(officeServiceImpl.findAll().size() - 1);
    assertEquals("Test office", lastLocation.getOfficeName());
}
```

Here's the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO office0_ (active_indicator, facility_code, office_code, office_name, head_count, lattitude, longitude, lert_indicator, country, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state_or_province, postal_code, updated_at, created_at) 
VALUES(1, '1','1','xyz','2',1.11111,2.22222,0,'US','fake address', '', '', 'x', 'YZ', '12345', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

There are no errors indicating that this record is not being added, and no messages indicating it is added for that matter.  Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue usually comes up when two Java processes are in fact accessing two different databases.

To avoid the issue, use the connection property `ifexists=true`, or the alternative property `create=false` for the connection that relies on the database to pre-exist. The connection attempt will simply fail if the database does not already exist.

The URL for a `file:` database should ideally be an absolute URL. Relative URL's are relative to the execution point of the Java process and usually point to different absolute paths.